# How to create a grid based on random shapes?

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, random, grid

How to create a "grid" using actionscript like the image below?

Basically you have an area of 1100x615 which should be filled with shapes that could be rotated and scaled...

Collision detection perhaps or something less cpu intensive for flash (as3) to manage?

[image: Grid]

Comment: What do you mean by grid? I was expecting [a tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid). I don't see anything in that image that I'd describe as a *grid*. Do you just mean that the space is filled with shapes?

Comment: I'm not good with this kind of stuff, but perhaps you are looking for Image Segmentation?

Comment: Looks like he wants to fit sprites into an atlas, but unlike usual rectangles bin packing, these are freeform shapes allowed to rotate and scale

Comment: Your "specs" are very much lacking. Why do you want to create something like this? Do shapes have to have a precise position in the image? How much can they be scaled or rotated? There are shapes appearing multiple times in your image, what about it? Do they have to be spaced by a certain distance?

Comment: Your image was most likely composed by hand and without needing to place a set number of images. Some images repeat and were probably chosen just to fill space. Doing the same with an algorithm may be a fun exercise but serves no practical game dev purpose.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in the first time... So here it goes, you have a canvas which will be filled with shapes as seen above, each shape can be scaled and rotated randomly. The same shape can appear more than once. The player is then asked a series of questions like "Find the five wrist watches" or " Find all the blue bags" etc. until all the shapes disappear...

Comment: And your question is about generating an image like that from a series of individual images, or about the selection of individual shapes in an image like this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(1)** You may be able to adapt an algorithm used for creating word clouds.

Here's [one example algorithm](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/about/), based on [Wordle's strategy](http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf). This works by choosing a start position/size/orientation for each object (generally starting with the biggest/most important ones), and trying to place it there. If it collides with an already-placed object, move it incrementally along a spiral expanding outward from the start position, and try again until you find a valid placement or you run out of places on the canvas.

This trial-and-error approach is slow, so you'll want a good way to accelerate your collision tests (some ideas at the links above), and possibly do the work in the background - say by generating level 2 off-screen while the player works on level 1.

**(2)** Another approach would be to use a [force-directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) to make objects jostle each other out of the way until a locally optimal spacing is found. Doing this with irregularly-shaped objects is nontrivial though. Once again this is a time-intensive iterative process, although you might be able to show it to the player before it's fully settled, turning the jello-like bobbing of the objects into an element of your game's style.

**(3)** A more experimental method would be to break your play space into polygonal cells (say, using a [Voronoi tesselation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)), then assign an object to each cell. You then try to fit each object within its cell confines as best you can by rotating & scaling within tolerances. This is likely to produce more gaps than either option above, but has the advantage that it can be done in one pass without massive iteration, or collision tests between two arbitrary shapes.