# How can I spawn objects in a volume without intersection?

Tags: c++, procedural-generation, intersection, spawning, collision-avoidance

I am generating a 3D scene that involves spawning lots of 3D objects in a finite volume. I need to avoid intersection of objects.

Comment: We're not a library search service, but we can help you write code that solves this problem if you can fill in a few more details. What kinds of shapes are your objects? What kind of representation do you use to express their shapes? What is the shape of the volume you're packing them in? What range of sizes/densities are we talking about here? From your research so far on [solving packing problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), what have you tried, and where have you run into difficulty?

Comment: [There are some strategies for a 2D version of this problem discussed here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/70631/39518) - you might find some inspirations that you can scale up to 3D.